# Allow empty query string in .htaccess (like server/param1//param3/)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got this htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((.|\r|\n)+)/? index.php?params=$1 [L,NC]
```

It allows me to send unlimited parameters to index.php, wich receives them inside the params array.
Linebreaks ('\r' / '\n') are allowed.

The problem I'm having is that when I send **server/param1/param2/param3**, $_GET['params'] will look like:

```
Array ( [0] => param1 [1] => param2 [2] => param3 )
```

But I send **server/param1//param3**, $_GET['params'] misses one key:

```
Array ( [0] => param1 [1] => param3 )
```

I want the server to answer with an empty value, not a deleted key:

```
Array ( [0] => param1 [1] => [2] => param3 )
```

Comment: `$_GET['params']` just goes as a string. Are you calling explode to make it an array?

Comment: True, $_GET['params'] comes in like param1/param2, so yes, I do an explode ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is the rule that you have it here. Do checkout my answer on other question you had posted, that won't cause this problem since it doesn't truncate multiple `//` into single `/` as you are experiencing because of captured string from `RewriteRule`.

Try this code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^params=.+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+[^/]+/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?params=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks! This indeed works! Your other answer caused problems with the directory the system was in, this one works like a charm.

Comment: Other answer should also work, I just didn't know your URL also has a dir before `/param1/param2/param3`. I had modified that answer also to make it work so essentially both ansewrs are same :)

Comment: And do remember that in future if you want original URL "as is" then don't grab a match from `RewriteRule`. `%{THE_REQUEST}` is best way to capture original unmodified URL segments.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done.
The reason for this is [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738), which defines the syntax of URLs.
HTTP URLs are defined like this:

```
; HTTP

httpurl        = "http://" hostport [ "/" hpath [ "?" search ]]
hpath          = hsegment *[ "/" hsegment ]
hsegment       = *[ uchar | ";" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" ]
search         = *[ uchar | ";" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" ]
```

which means that in a HTTP path, no double slash (empty hsegment) is allowed. That's why  HTTP servers simply interpret double slashes in a URL path as one slash.

Comment: I've seen it enabled inside of IIS, so despite the fact that it isn't allowed, it is possible - I just don't know how to realize it inside of Apache ;)

Comment: We all know Microsoft likes to define their own standards, but I'm pretty sure Apache adheres to them. I would bet you can't do it with Apache.

Comment: True story about MS right there. But, I don't necessarily need // to work. I just want to have the empty data instead of no data. Maybe there is a way to let .htaccess rewrite // to /_/ as mentioned below?

Comment: What would you have your bet for? Checkout @anubhava's answer ;)! It IS possible ;)

Comment: So it is possible, but it still violates standards and all that's good and holy.

Comment: I won't let you start a true || false fight with me :p. I'm just saying that it is possible whether you told me "This cannot be done" and "I would bet you can't do it with Apache" ;).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this approach of having unlimited number of parameters without the actual parameter names might cause confusion in the future, please look at the following example:

```
server/param1//param3/param4///param5/param6////param7
```

Your code is already complicated to parse those parameters and to verify which is which, I would strongly suggest having a named parameters.

Comment: The names come in inside of my script. I'm building some kind of REST-server to connect an iOS app to a back-office. The first param always is the method that gets called. Inside the method all of the parameters have their own purpose.

Comment: As stated before it is not possible to have double slash, but you could do something like `server/param1/something/param2/_/param3/somethingelse` this enforces both correct parameter types and more control over what is being sent to your REST like service. You would just need to rewrite the `.htaccess` file a little bit.

Comment: Is there a way to rewrite // to /_/ then?